# 800 MHz DDR2 RAM shows half of memory speed on my machine

Tags: memory, cpu, performance, acer-veriton, memory-speed

I have an Acer Veriton l670 mini PM. My machine has:

- E8400 3 GHz dual core CPU
- 2x2, 4 GB DDR2 800 MHz RAM dual channel (Kingston acr256x64d2s800c6)
- 320 GB hard disk 7200 rpm

While this is not a very bad PC, I can't play Civilization V with the lowest options (it lags in game).
I decided to check my PC with CPU-Z software. I am confused that it shows my memory running at half speed.
Is there any jumper to change the speed?

[image: ram details]
[image: slot1]
[image: slot2]
[image: cpu details]
[image: motherboard details]

Comment: Sorry, but your PC is just old and not built for gaming. Granted, it's not _very_ bad - less powerful machines did exist - but it's far from being reasonably equipped, too. This CPU was released 10 years ago. Civ5 isn't very demanding, but without dedicated graphics card you're way below minimum system requirements. It may be (barely) sufficient for browsing the Internet and basic data processing, but it's completely unsuitable for gaming without a dedicated GPU.

Comment: @gronostaj Lack of a dedicated GPU doesn't automatically make a system useless for gaming.  Recent iGPU's on Intel chips do just fine with most games, even some triple A titles, you just wont' get amazing graphics quality (but if the graphics quality is why you're playing the game, then you're missing the point).  That said, the GPU being discussed is not one which is suitable for gaming, regardless of whether it's a dGPU or not.

Answer (score 2):

The "DDR" in DDR2 stands for Double Data Rate. It means that data is transferred twice on each clock cycle. Your RAM expects a clock speed of 400 MHz and is listed as 800 MHz because the double data rate means that it transfers data 800 million times per second.

This terminology is used for all DDR RAM and does not indicate a problem. See the [DDR SDRAM article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR_SDRAM) on Wikipedia for more information.

Your problem running Civilization V is likely to be the graphic processor. Your PC is not designed for gaming and uses Intel GMA4500 graphics integrated on the motherboard. The minimum graphics capability for Civilization V is "VIDEO CARD: 256 MB ATI HD2600 XT or better, 256 MB nVidia 7900 GS or better, or Core i3 or better integrated graphics".

If you want to use this PC for gaming, you should look at adding a dedicated graphics card. Unfortunately your PC's only expansion slot is a PCI Express x1 slot. That won't support most modern graphics cards, but if you search on "PCIe x1 graphics" should can find some older x1 cards for sale. They won't run the latest games, but can probably handle Civilization V.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot currently play Civilization V on the lowest options.

Your DDR2 frequency running at 400 MHz is not the reason you are unable to run Civilization V. Your system simply does not meet the system requirements.

> I decided to check my system with CPU Z, but I am confused by the results, the software shows that my memory is running at half speed.

Your memory is running at their full potential.  Your DDR2 modules are actually running at 400 MHz modules, but their transfer speeds are 800 MT/sec, but neither of these specifications is the reason you cannot play Civilization V.

[image]

Source: [DDR2 SDRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM)

> Is there any jumper to change state?

You cannot change the frequency of a DDR2 memory module with a jumper.  The only way to have the memory run faster than 400 MHz, is to overclock your memory, and your system specifications make that impossible.