# Why are my RAMs operating at 1200MHz

Tags: memory, hardware-acceleration, underclock

[image]

I just bought 2 [Corsair 32GB 2400MHz RAM sticks](https://www.scorptec.com.au/product/Memory/DDR4/78077-CMK32GX4M1A2400C16), but when I check them on CPU-Z, I see they are operating at 1200MHz.

Could someone help to bring them back to 2400MHz?

Thanks

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1379754/403203

Comment: hi @MC10 thanks for sharing it!!! Could you please post an answer and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: We'll likely mark it as a duplicate then, since the information in that question and answer pertain to this one, and so users can be directed there as well. Essentially it's the same thing, it displays half the speed because DDR is Double Data Rate